# Outlook Signature By Time

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, signature

Good Afternoon,

I currently have a client who is experiencing some issues with his signatures in Outlook.

As part of his business he has a disclaimer attached to the bottom of his signature   to state that the email was sent during work hours.

He is chasing to find out if there is any way, beyond manually selecting between two email signatures, to have a signature automatically used when replying/sending emails during certain times and another post those times.

So far as I am aware and those I work with this is not possible however I thought I would ask the question in case.

Comment: One common way to do it is have the official "full" signature in his Outlook, and another "on my phone" signature on his phone for when he's not at his work PC.  If you need to do it on the same PC, you can have a secondary sig by using a second email program or webmail, if available.  Why differentiate the signatures instead of putting office hours in the one signature?

Comment: No real reason from what I can tell, thinking its more just due to preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a macro that should be able to do the job you seek; just modify it to your liking.

```
Public Sub CreateMessageSignature()
    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Dim theDay As Integer
    Dim hoursStart, hoursEnd As Double
    Dim custom As String
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(MailItem)
    theDay = Weekday(Now)
    hoursStart = TimeValue("8:00:00 am")
    hoursEnd = TimeValue("4:30:00 pm")
    custom = "This message is sent out of office hours."
    If theDay > 1 And theDay < 7 Then ' Mon-Fri
        If Now > hoursStart And Now < hoursEnd Then ' The current time is between office hours
           custom = "This message is sent during office hours."
        End If
    End If
    With objMsg
      .HTMLBody = "Greetings,<br><br>&emsp;Sincerely,<br><br>John Smith<br>contact@example.com<br>(123)-456-7890<br>" & custom & strBuffer
      .Display
    End With
```

End Sub

If you don't know how to set it up:

1. Enable the Developer menu in Outlook: File → Options → Customize Ribbon → Bubble in the Developer menu.
2. Create the macro: Developer menu → Macros → Type in a name, particularly `CreateMessageSignature` (unless you want to rename the function which you can) → Click "Create" → Copy and paste the macro (beware of indentations) → Modify to your liking → Save (Ctrl+S)
3. Now add the button to the Home section of the ribbon: File → Options → Customize Ribbon → Create a new group in "Home (Mail)", name it to your liking → Select it and on the right side find the macro you just made and press "Add".

Good Luck!

Comment: Cheers mate, will give it a whirl!